# Why Overload resolution is unable to decide which version of an overloaded function to initialize an std::function object?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, overload-resolution

I have this example about `std::function`:

```
int add(int x, int y, int z) {return x + y + z;}
int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int, int)> fn = add; // error

    int(*pfn)(int, int) = add; // OK
    fn = pfn; // ok  fn is bound to add(int, int)
    std::cout << fn(5, 7) << std::endl; // 12

}
```

- Why Overload resolution doesn't resolve which version of `add` when initializing `fn` but is able to initialize the function pointer `pfn`?
- Is there a workaround rather than using function pointer to decide which version of an overloaded function as an initializer to an `std::function` object?

Comment: `std::function` has a templated constructor that takes pretty much anything. There's no signal for the compiler to choose the correct overload. One possible workaround is an explicit cast:  `std::function<int(int, int)> fn = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(add);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yes I think it is good idea to use `static_cast` here thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Why Overload resolution doesn't resolve which version of `add` when initializing `fn` but is able to initialize the function pointer `pfn`?

Because [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) is performed in the initialization of function pointer (like `pfn`), based on the type of the function pointer.

> In all these contexts, the function selected from the overload set is the function whose type matches the pointer to function, reference to function, or pointer to member function type that is expected by *target*: the object or reference being initialized, the left-hand side of the assignment, function or operator parameter, the return type of a function, the target type of a cast, or the type of the template parameter, respectively.

On the other hand, such overload resolution doesn't happen when initializing a `std::function`, which has a constructor template and the template parameter needs to be deduced from the function argument; the compiler can't choose one for the deduction.

As the workaround, you can apply [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Notes) to specify the overload you want explicitly.

> `static_cast` may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type

```
std::function<int(int, int)> fn = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(add);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the function pointer case, C++ has a special rule that permits a sort of "time travelling" lookup. It can perform overload resolution on a name, based on what you're going to assign/initialise the name to.

This is basically a hack built into the language (rules in [[over.over]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over)).

No other part of the language works this way. For example, where newcomers often expect that after writing `float x = 1/2` the value of `x` will be `0.5`, we have to explain that the fact you're initialising a `float` has no relevance to the types or calculation of the expression `1/2`.

This hack was not extended to `std::function`. Presumably that is because adding hacks is bad, and because it is not needed for this case. Why not? Because you can still deploy the hack indirectly with a `static_cast` on the RHS of your `std::function` initialisation:

```
std::function<int(int, int)> fn = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(add);
```

… and there's your workaround.

Comment: Why do you call it a "hack" rather than a "feature"?

Comment: @Maestro "Hack" is subset of "feature". I deem a feature a hack when it utilises idioms or conventions not found elsewhere in the surrounding context, and which are in some ways antithetical to the existing conventions found elsewhere. Such a thing is a hack because violating the established design bible was seemingly necessary in order to provide the feature, so an exception had to be made. I don't think this is an unusual usage of the term.